# AWS PrivateLink between accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I'm having trouble with communicating from one AWS to another through PrivateLink.

In one of the accounts I've set up a NLB and an endpoint service in a VPC. In the same account I have and APIGateway which for now simply returns status 200.

I've whitelisted my second account and from there created a VPC Endpoint to the first accounts endpoint service and accepted the connection.

From my second account what I'm trying to do is use the created vpce address to make a HTTP request from a lambda in the second account to the first accounts apigateway endpoint, using the apigateway address as a Host header. I've made sure that the second accounts lambda is within the same vpc, subnet and security group as the vpc endpoint.

But when I make the request from the lambda it just spins for 15sec until it times out.

I feel like I'm missing something but I'm not sure where. Has anyone got this setup working?

Comment: did you ever manage to get this working? I seem to be in a similar boat where the VPC Endpoint Service is working (a VPC Endpoint in the same account connects and I can hit the service via the endpoint) but I can't make it work across accounts (the endpoint connects, but requests time out)

Comment: Unfortunately no sorry, I never got this solution to work as far is I remember.

Comment: Aha, no worries. Thanks for replying!